# Permiso denegado al acceder a la base de datos MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, linux, centos

Servidor HTTPD Independiente (con Wordpress) y Servidor BDD Independiente (MySQL) - Permiso denegado al acceder a la base de datos.

Llevo días dedicándome a aprender el uso de la herramienta ansible y el desarrollo de playbooks para la configuración de un entorno web de pruebas. He realizado múltiples playbooks para configurar un servidor web, servidor de base de datos, balanceador de carga y por último estaba configurando un playbook para la descarga y configuración de wordpress, pero al terminar de configurar el mismo me muestra el siguiente error

```
Warning: mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2002): Permission denied in /var/www/wordpress/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1633

Deprecated: mysql_connect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead in /var/www/wordpress/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1665

Warning: mysql_connect(): Permission denied in /var/www/wordpress/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1665
Permission denied
```

He revisado las líneas de los ficheros indicados y son las funciones para establecer conexión con la base de datos de PHP.
He comprobado que el servidor de base de datos se encuentra operativo y accesible para otras máquinas a través de mysql, el servidor web que utiliza el servidor apache (httpd) posee también las dependencias PHP requeridas para establecer la conexión con la base de datos, pero a la hora de aplicar el archivo de configuración de Wordpress (wp-config-php) me muestra ese error (esto si configuro manualmente el archivo, si intento utilizar la instalación gráfica me muestra el error de conexión pero sin mostrar el mensaje de error que acabo de indicar). El usuario de base de datos utilizado posee todos los permisos.
¿Alguna sugerencia? Muchas gracias de antemano y un saludo.

ENTORNO UTILIZADO:
1.Máquina Virtual CentOS Balanceador de Carga
2.MV CentOS Webserver1
3.MV CentOS Webserver2
4.MV CentOS Dbserver
5.Conexión establecida en adaptador puente para probar directamente desde mi máquina anfitriona.

Comment: En tu pregunta no queda claro desde dónde te quieres conectar exactamente. El 1er mensaje dice claramente que el permiso fue denegado, tienes que investigar por qué (por ejemplo, puede que Wordpress tenga su propia BD y usuario y estés intentando con otro usuario). Los otros dos mensajes indican que intentas usar una función obsoleta. la API `mysql_` fue declarada obsoleta hace ya años y tendrías que cambiar a `mysqli` o a PDO. De todos modos, para ayudarte más precisamente debes dar más detalles sobre el contexto: desde donde te conectas, a qué te conectas, cómo te conectas, con qué, etc...

Comment: Buenas Cedano, lo siento si no he sido suficientemente claro. Me quedó claro que el mensaje muestra error de permisos y ya me he asegurado de que el usuario que he creado específicamente para wordpress a través de mi playbook de ansible junto a la base de datos correctamente tenga todos los permisos. Estoy 100% seguro de que el servidor de base de datos funciona correctamente ya que puedo conectarme desde mi máquina anfitriona hasta el servidor bdd. Tiene pinta de ser un problema de la API que comentas y poseo la dependencia php-pdo, pero no me queda claro cómo usar esa en específico

Comment: Aquí ha varias preguntas con respuestas que explican cómo pasar de `mysql_` a PDO o a `mysqli`. Revisa esas preguntas, intenta migrar el código y si tienes problemas nos dices. Con un simple mensaje de error lo más que podemos hacer es decirte lo que ese mensaje dice. Como comentas, ya lo tienes claro. Entonces hay que pasar a otro nivel de resolución del problema, basándote en código concreto.

Comment: Muchas gracias Cedano, al cambiar de mysql_ a mysqli conseguí solucionar el error de la obsolescencia de mysql_. El error de permisos era por una regla de SELinux Booleans para habilitar la conexión de httpd con la red. Muchas gracias :)

Comment: Revertí tu edición pues no es correcto colocar solucionado en el título de tu pregunta, en su pugar dispones abajo de la zona de respuestas donde la puedes publicar

Answer (score 0):

Conseguí solucionar estos mensajes de error. Para solucionar el error de permisos tuve que aplicar una regla SELinux Boolean para habilitar el acceso del servidor httpd a la red

```
sudo setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect 1
```

Para solucionar el error de la obsolescencia de la función de mysql_, tuve que modificar el archivo de wordpress que realiza la función de conexión con la base de datos (wordpress/wp-includes/wp-db.php) y editar las líneas de código dónde se conecta con la base de datos:

```
$this->dbh = mysqli_connect( $this->dbhost, $this->dbuser, $this->dbpassword, $new_link, $client_flags );
$this->dbh = mysqli_real_connect( $this->dbhost, $this->dbuser, $this->dbpassword, $new_link, $client_flags );
```

Cambié 2 funciones mysql_connect y 2 funciones mysql_real_connect (para aplicar a todas las condiciones ya que se encuentran siendo utilizadas bajo una condicional)